# is it possible to get a subset of a 2-dimensional Set in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I want to determin optimal charging for BEV along a grid line. Therefore I use `pyomo` to build a LP model describing the optimization. I have a Set of times (one day in quarter hour steps):

```
model.times = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(96)))
```

and a Set of nodes:

```
model.buses = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(6)))
```

I use these both sets to index the Variables and Constraints. For example, I have one Constraint tracking the SOCs of the BEVs:
[image]

```
def track_socs_rule(model, t, b):
    if t >= model.bevs[b].t_start and t <= model.bevs[b].t_target:
        return (model.SOC[t, b] + model.I[t, b] * model.voltages[b] * model.resolution/60 / 1000
                / model.bevs[b].e_bat*100 - model.SOC[t+1, b]) == 0
    else:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip
```

So i have to take care inside the rule defining the Constraint, that only valid timesteps are included (namely when the BEV at the according node is charging). It works, and I get proper results -  but there has to be a more elegant way. I thought of defining a Set that only contains valid timesteps, something like:

```
model.valid_subset = pe.Set(within=model.times*model.charger_buses,
                            initialize=[[t for t in model.times if t >= model.bevs[b].t_start and
                                         t <= model.bevs[b].t_target] for b in model.charger_buses]
```

But this gives me an Error:

```
ValueError: Cannot add value([bla, bla, ...], [bla, bla...], ...) to Set valid_subset.
The value is not in the domain valid_subset_domain
```

Here is a minimal working example that should reproduce the error:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe

class BEV:
    def __init__(self, home_bus, e_bat, soc_start, soc_target, t_start, t_target, resolution):
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.home_bus = home_bus
        self.e_bat = e_bat
        self.soc_start = soc_start
        self.soc_target = soc_target
        self.t_start = int(t_start * 60/self.resolution)
        self.t_target = int(t_target * 60/self.resolution)


RESOLUTION = 15 # minutes

home_buses = [0, 2, 3, 4]
e_bats = [50, 50, 50, 50] # kWh
soc_starts = [20, 25, 20, 30] # %
soc_targets = [80, 75, 90, 100] # %
t_starts = [10, 12, 9, 15] # hours
t_targets = [19, 18, 15, 23] # hours

bevs = []
for pos in range(4):
    bev = BEV(home_bus=home_buses[pos], e_bat=e_bats[pos], soc_start=soc_starts[pos],
              soc_target=soc_targets[pos], t_start=t_starts[pos],
              t_target=t_targets[pos], resolution=RESOLUTION)
    bevs.append(bev)

solver = pe.SolverFactory('glpk')
model = pe.ConcreteModel()

model.bevs = {bev.home_bus: bev for bev in bevs}
model.resolution = RESOLUTION
model.times = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(int(24 * 60/RESOLUTION))))
model.buses = pe.Set(initialize=list(range(6)))
model.charger_buses = pe.Set(within=model.buses, initialize=[bus for bus in model.bevs])
#model.valid_subset = pe.Set(within=model.times*model.charger_buses,
                            #initialize=[[t for t in model.times if t >= model.bevs[b].t_start
                                         #and t <= model.bevs[b].t_target] for b in model.charger_buses])

model.voltages = pe.Param(model.buses, initialize={i: 400-i/2 for i in model.buses})

model.SOC = pe.Var(model.times*model.charger_buses, domain=pe.PositiveReals)
model.I = pe.Var(model.times*model.charger_buses, domain=pe.PositiveReals)

def track_socs_rule(model, t, b):
    # instead leave if (once indexed in model.valid_subset)
    if t >= model.bevs[b].t_start and t <= model.bevs[b].t_target:
        return (model.SOC[t, b] + model.I[t, b] * model.voltages[b] * model.resolution/60 /1000
                /model.bevs[b].e_bat*100 - model.SOC[t+1, b]) == 0

    else:
        return pe.Constraint.Skip

# instead index in model.valid_subset (once it works...)
model.track_socs = pe.Constraint(model.times*model.charger_buses, rule=track_socs_rule)
model.track_socs.pprint()
```

Once one uncomments the line with the `model.valid_subset` the error occurs. My hopings are, that once I use this "clever" index, I can leave away the if in `track_socs_rule`, because the components are allready properly indexed. This will also help me with the upper and lower bounds for `I` and `SOC` (they aren't even included in the code - i left them for the sake of simplicity).

So after a lot of explanation, **my question:**

is there a way to construct a subset of a 2-d Set in `pyomo`?

Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely is a way to construct such a desired subset. In fact, your formulation is kinda fine, you need to refine some mistakes.

1. In the line `model.valid_subset = pe.Set(within=model.times*model.charger_buses,...` you're telling the model to constraint the subset to be within the `cross product` of `model.times` and `model.charger_buses`, but you're trying to initialize the subset just with `t`, therefore, you cannot add such a subset, since domain is `(t_i,b_i)` and you're just adding `t_i`.
2. For a `Set` component, `initialize` arg should be a list of actual values (I think that any np.array-like iterable should work, but not fully sure), but you're passing a list of lists, then, and error will raise. You need to flatten your list of lists into a single list.

To flatten your list of list, I will be using `itertools` [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists), but you can do it the way you want it.

```
import itertools
#All your model
...
model.valid_subset = pe.Set(within=model.times*model.charger_buses,
                            initialize=list(itertools.chain(*[[(t,b) for t in model.times if t >= model.bevs[b].t_start
                                         and t <= model.bevs[b].t_target] for b in model.charger_buses])))
```

You may want to construct any sub-set outside the actual `initialize` arg. It may be the same list comprenhension, but not in the actual `arg` of `Set` (or any) component. This would help to make it more readable.

Comment: perfect, that solved my problem! :) Thank you!